# DataGridView Search and Filter Data in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, search, gridview, datagridview

i use this code to Search and Filter Data from DataGridView that connect with 2 table (inner join) but nothing happend ! 
here is the Code :

```
DataTable dt;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sql = @"SELECT Invoice.[InvoiceID], Invoice.[CustomerID], Invoice.[Date], Invoice.[Amount], Invoice.[Paid], Invoice.[Rest], Invoice.[PaymentType], Invoice.[Shipped], Customer.[CustomerID], Customer.[Name], Customer.[Tell], Customer.[Address], Customer.[Comment] FROM [Invoice] INNER JOIN [Customer] ON Invoice.[CustomerID] = Customer.[CustomerID]";
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RechnungConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            conn.Close();
        }
    } 
    protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            DataView DV = new DataView(dt);
            DV.RowFilter = string.Format("Name LIKE '%{0}%'", TextBox1.Text);
            GridView1.DataSource = DV;

    }
```

and this is Textbox and Gridview in Asp.net form :

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="InvoiceID" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered" AllowSorting="true">
```

if some one know how to fix this or have better way for search and filter data in GridView plz help me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
DataTable dt;
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sql = @"SELECT Invoice.[InvoiceID], Invoice.[CustomerID], Invoice.[Date], Invoice.[Amount], Invoice.[Paid], Invoice.[Rest], Invoice.[PaymentType], Invoice.[Shipped], Customer.[CustomerID], Customer.[Name], Customer.[Tell], Customer.[Address], Customer.[Comment] FROM [Invoice] INNER JOIN [Customer] ON Invoice.[CustomerID] = Customer.[CustomerID]";
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RechnungConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            conn.Close();
        }
    } 

protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           dt = new DataTable();

            cmd2 =
                new SqlCeCommand(string.Format(@"SELECT Invoice.[InvoiceID], Invoice.[CustomerID], Invoice.[Date], Invoice.[Amount], Invoice.[Paid], Invoice.[Rest], Invoice.[PaymentType], Invoice.[Shipped], Customer.[CustomerID], Customer.[Name], Customer.[Tell], Customer.[Address], Customer.[Comment] FROM [Invoice] INNER JOIN [Customer] ON Invoice.[CustomerID] = Customer.[CustomerID] where Name LIKE '%{0}%'", TextBox1.Text));
            try
            {
                adp1.SelectCommand = cmd2;
                adp1.Fill(dt);
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }

    }
```

If you still had problems, let me know. (Movafagh bashi)

Comment: I try this but nothing happend aggain :) , and there was some little error's in this code like ( adp1 is sda ) or Sqlcommand without connection in TextChanged ! ( Shoma ham hamintoor )

Comment: U were suppose to have a connectionstring variable for that one. But as @SURFThru said, your page_load event may fires. Check it.

Comment: i fix that search text box but now the problem is when write in textbox i have to press ENTER , do u know any Event handler like KeyPress ( in windows form ) that work in asp.net ?!

Answer (score 0):

Maziar,

Your text box change event is firing but your Page_Load fires and loads your grid again. If you put it in debug you will see your page load fires again and resets your gird to look like the filter never took.

If you have the budget implementing a 3rd party grid control can add many of the filtering features and more right out of the box. I have not used the standard grid in sometime and use DevExpress grids in all my sites.

Take a look at [this link](http://demos.devexpress.com/aspxgridviewdemos/Filtering/HeaderFilter.aspx) for the the powerful filtering you get out of a [DevExpress Grid](http://demos.devexpress.com/aspxgridviewdemos/Filtering/HeaderFilter.aspx).

The product pays for itself in the number of hours you will save, and the awesome set of features you can give to your end users.

Comment: i try my code without page_load and load data in gridView with Button but doesn't work that too ! DevExpress is expensive i am writing this web app for a small money :)